# mbed Alternative to FreeRTOS's vTaskDelayUntil()

Tags: mbed, freertos

FreeRTOS's vTaskDelayUntil() function causes a thread/task to unblock at an absolute time, therefore ensuring that threads are "awakened" in consistent time intervals.

Does the mbed platform offer something like this? As far as I know, the Thread::Wait function causes the thread to unblock relative to the time it was called.

Comment: does this help: https://docs.mbed.com/docs/mbed-os-api-reference/en/latest/APIs/tasks/tasks/

Comment: It should be obvious that the difference between an increment wait and a wait-until is just a little math based on the current time.  That actual significant things like the scheduler *latency* guarantee around resumption (if there even is any) are unmentioned.  So it's unclear what the practical or meaningful question actually is.